# where are all unsaved files from microsoft office suit?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010

I was trying to locate lost Excel files that were autosaved during computer shutoff. While I did find many autosaved files when I opened Excel, they were not listed in either a chronological or alphabetical order. I then went to AppData > Local > Mirosoft > Office > UnsavedFiles. To my surprise, the folder is EMPTY. So where are those autosaved Excel files ?

I assume this question is applicable to other Microsoft Office files as well. So any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This question shows a serious lack of research. I did a quick Internet search and came up with [How to recover a lost Word document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316951). The introduction describes exactly what you experienced. If you have exhausted these options, the files are most likely gone.

Comment: @CharlieRB, I think you did not read the question clearly - (1) it's not that I could NOT find autosaved doc. I could. It's that in Excel (or WORD), they were not listed in a "searchable" way. I tried to find a searchable way so to sort them by the dates they were created. (2) as also stated in the link you provided, the autosaved files should be stored in Local>Microsoft>Office>UnsavedFiles folder. But when I manually opened it, it's EMPTY - whereas the files were CLEARLY shown available in Excel/WORD. So I was wondering if they could have been saved in any other place.